# I setup a DNS but I don't Get Response From my Domain And IntoDNS have errors why?

Tags: centos, domain, bind, nameserver

I Setup DNS in my VPS with BIND 9 and Everything is OK but in IntoDNS There Are Some errors 30 min ago I also Added 2nd Nameserver but I am Getting Error here is the output.

```error
    Reverse MX A records (PTR)  ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are:
212.178.5.194.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your ips
```

```error
Stealth NS records sent Stealth NS records were sent:
ns2.mydomain.ir
```

```error
Missing nameservers reported by parent  FAIL: The following nameservers are listed at your nameservers as nameservers for your domain, but are not listed at the parent nameservers (see RFC2181 5.4.1). You need to make sure that these nameservers are working.If they are not working ok, you may have problems!
ns2.mydomain.ir
```

```error
    Multiple Nameservers    ERROR: Looks like you have less than 2 nameservers. According to RFC2182 section 5 you must have at least 3 nameservers, and no more than 7. Having 2 nameservers is also ok by me.
```

EDIT: mydomain.ir isn't My Real Domain if the real Domain Is needed Tell me.

Comment: Give us the real domain, please.

Comment: buymeacookie.ir @ceejayoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages you quoted report two distinct problems with your domain, both confirmed by direct queries:

1. You list `mail.buymeacookie.ir` as incoming mail server (MX) for your domain. General consensus requires that mail servers have matching forward and reverse DNS entries. `mail.buymeacookie.ir` resolves to `194.5.178.212` but `194.5.178.212` does *not* resolve back to `mail.buymeacookie.ir`. In fact `194.5.178.212` does not resolve at all. It does not have a `PTR` record.
2. You claim that you added a second nameserver. However right now your domain lists only one single name server (NS) record, `ns1.buymeacookie.ir`, even if queried directly at `ns1.buymeacookie.ir`. You may have forgotten to increment the serial or to reload the zone.